# Slow codeception coverage in docker

Tags: php, docker, yii, codeception, docker-for-mac

I have a trouble with PHP codeception coverage report in the docker container.
For example the same test with

```
codeception run unit
```

gets me (72.79s), but with coverage flag

```
codeception run unit --coverage --coverage-html
```

it gets me (4,412.27s). 
Some test just crushed with:

> ERROR: Bad response from Docker engine.

In codeception.yml include section I set only *.php files and folders with code.

My system: Codeception 2.3.3, Docker EDGE 17.06.0-rc1-ce-mac13, Yii1 framework.

I tried to use new performance tuning by docker https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/, It helped a little bit but result above already with improve.

Comment: Try docker-4-mac as well: https://github.com/IFSight/d4m-nfs . I watched coverage increase test execution time to such a point we set it up to run once at midnight. Even then though, yours would still timeout....what other Codeception modules / configuration can you share?